# Dynamic Variable Increment

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, increment

I have a few variables

```
var itemCount = 0;
var pageCount = 0;
var groupCount = 0;
```

Along with those variables, I have three buttons with data attributes that match these three variables

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#activeQ" data-count="item">ITEM</button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#activeQ" data-count="page">PAGE</button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#activeQ" data-count="group">GROUP</button>
```

What I want to do is each time I click a specific button, it increments that variable, ex. I click the ITEM button, itemCount adds 1.

I thought I had the function correct, but when I click it, the count is not incrementing *(I am displaying some other information in a modal popup as well)*:

```
$('#activeQ').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var aCat = button.data('count');
    var theCount = eval(aCat+"Count");
    theCount++;
    console.log(theCount);
});
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why are you using `eval`?  It can be problematic in many contexts, and I'm seeing no reason for it to be used above...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49285999/8284239

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `window['varName']` to access a variable :

```
$('#activeQ').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var aCat = button.data('count');
    window[aCat+"Count"]++;
    console.log(window[aCat+"Count"]);
});
```

Comment: I'm currently at work, and I had to wait to mark this answer correct. Priorities, mate.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `eval` at all..

The best way to do this is to keep your variables in an object:

```
var counters = {
    item: 0,
    page: 0,
    group: 0
};
$('#activeQ').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var aCat = button.data('count');
    counters[aCat]++;
    console.log(counters);
});
```

It avoids polluting your global space with variables, and keeps them together as they're related.